# php redirect multiple users to multiple pages after login

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a login with multiple users. i have connected phpMyAdmin database and single user login is working properly. with login.php code it is not redirected to the intended page.dbconnect.php is working.

**login.php**

```
<?php

require('dbconnect.php');

 if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pw'])){

    $email=$_POST['uname'];
    $pw=$_POST['pw'];

if ($stmt = mysql_query("SELECT role FROM register WHERE 'email'= ? and 'pw'= ? ")) {
    /* bind parameters for username and password */
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $pw);


    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
        // bind the result to a variable
        $stmt->bind_result($role);
        $stmt->fetch();


        switch( $role ){

            case 'admin':
                header("location:admin.php");
                exit();

            case 'trackcoordinator':
                header("location:trackco.php");
                exit();

            case 'reviewer':
                header("location:reviewer.php");
                exit();

            case 'author':
                header("location:sub.php");
                exit();

            default:
                echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }

    }

    $stmt->close();
}
}

//$db->close();

?>
```

This is the register table. And data is fetching from this one for login process:

[image]

Comment: Is the login info correct? and it looks like you saving your passwords in plain text. and Dont use mysql use mysqli or PDO

Comment: login info is correct. when this code is running there is no any error msr. it reloads the same page as blank one

Comment: echo $role what do you get?

Comment: Also same blank page

Comment: edit your question and show your database tables

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: It seems like you are mixing up [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions e.g. `mysql_query()` with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions e.g. `$stmt->bind_param(...)`. Choose one or the other (better to use `mysqli` as `mysql` has been deprecated for a long time). Also remove the single quotes around `email` and `pw` in your query string.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mikey pointed out you are mixing `mysql_query` with `mysqli`'s statement preparation and binding. And you are also misusing the quotes in the query.

let's suppose your dbconnect.php looks like this

```
<?php
$db= new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
?>
```

then your login.php line 10 (the if statement) should be like

```
if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT role FROM register WHERE email = ? and pw = ? ")) { // You can either use backquotes (`email`) or no quotes
```

Then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `exit()` with `break()`, also I've noticed you use `=` instead of `==` in the `if()` statement. Try changing that too.

EDIT:
Another, better way to do multiple users redirection is to have an extra column in the database table, called access_level(or something like that), with int values like 1,2,3..., and then checking the access level of the current user and redirecting to different url's depending on the user's access level